# Detecting pulses of one nanosecond length

Tags: pins, time

As the title suggests, I want to detect extremely weak (~20mV) and short pulses: between 900ps and 1,5ns in length. I do not really care about the readout time or hold time after a pulse is detected.

Since the Arduino itself is not able to do the job, my first guess was that I would need to use a monoestable multivibrator.

After looking for the fastest in the market, I found the SN74LVC1G123 by TI. However, they state that the minimum input pulse length is 2ns, so that they may not suit my needs. Moreover, due to the weakness of the pulse, I may need to use a voltage comparator before, and I did not find any that can work with such short pulses.

Another option I thought about was adding a low pass filter before the multivibrator to widen the pulse a bit. However, my original pulse is already a weak signal (~20mV,) and the filter can basically destroy the signal.

Edit: may a charge sensitive amplifier be a solution?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132924/discussion-on-question-by-user3141592-detecting-pulses-of-one-nanosecond-length).